# Sails.js: calling controller method from unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sails.js

I would ask for some assistance. I am trying to make a method which can be called for unit test & called when specific route is triggered. `createFromRoute()` works just fine. If I call create() directly, I am getting an error.

## User controller

```
module.exports = {

  /**
   * UserController.createFromRoute()
   */
  createFromRoute: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('>>>', 'Routing to UserController.createFromRoute()');

    // Calling create method
    this.create(req.params.all())
      .then(function(user) {
        res.json(user);
      })
      .fail(res.badRequest);
  },

  create: function(data) {
    console.log('>>>', 'Entering create() function.');
    return User.create(data);
  },

};
```

## Sample test

```
var UserController = require('../../api/controllers/UserController.js');

describe('testing', function() {
  data = {};
  UserController.create(data);
});
```

## Error

```
>>> Entering create() function.
path/api/controllers/UserController.js:28
  return User.create(data);
           ^
ReferenceError: User is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `User` will be available only after you lift the app. Did you [launched sails in a bootstrap file](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing)?

```
// /test/bootstrap.test.js
var Sails = require('sails'),
  sails;

before(function(done) {

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
  this.timeout(5000);

  Sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
  }, function(err, server) {
    sails = server;
    if (err) return done(err);
    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  Sails.lower(done);
});
```

> Since your models are converted to waterline collections on lift, it
>   is necessary to lift your sailsApp before trying to test them (This
>   applies similarly to controllers and other parts of your app, so be
>   sure to call this file first).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did but this didn't resolve my issue.